# Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 in #Flutter

Tags: flutter, api

Code :

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&callback=test&appid=53ae74e992cf5d115dadab5170a3db90'));

```
// print(response.body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String data = response.body;

  var jsonData = jsonDecode(data)['weather'][0]['description'];
  print(jsonData);
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
}
```

Error:

```
FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at Object._parseJson (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:51151:19)
    at JsonDecoder.convert (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:48968:22)
    at JsonCodec.decode (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:48661:48)
    at Object.jsonDecode (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:51141:25)
    at getData (http://localhost:49319/packages/weather_app/screens
    at getData.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49319/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could display the response as that is where the error lies.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. By including the `callback` parameter you've asked the server to wrap the result in a Javascript funtion. Change it to `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=53ae74e992cf5d115dadab5170a3db90`

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any JSON at all. I was checking the url response and its  not returning JSON, but wrapped JSON in javascript function.

Try calling without callback `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=53ae74e992cf5d115dadab5170a3db90`

Answer (score -1):

JSON file was not in correct format. So, i have to re-format it then now it's working fine.